# Changing the color within a command to an environment

Tags: environments

I hope this is not a stupid question but I feel like I've tried everything, even stupid ideas at this point.

I am using a CV template which defines an environment for entry lists and then uses a command to add an entry. The environment and command are defined as such:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}%
    \begin{itemize}[label={},itemindent=-0.5em,leftmargin=0.5em]#4\end{itemize}\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

(I'm leaving in all the details in case any weird setting I have is having an impact)

For the last entry #4 there is a color setting. I would like to change the color of just one word within #4 like so:

```
\entry
{2016 - 2018}
{Bachelor {\normalfont Pen Spinning}}
{Trump University}
{\item {\color{black}Final Grade:} A
\item {\color{black}Achievements:} Runners-up Spinner of the Year
}
```

but it won't let me.
[image]
I suspect it's overwriting the text color in the environment command. Interestingly, if I do something like this:

```
\entry
{2016 - 2018}
{Bachelor {\normalfont Pen Spinning}}
{Trump University}
{\item {\color{black}\texttt{Final Grade:}} A
\item {\color{black}Achievements:} Runners-up Spinner of the Year
}
```

It does change the color to black. But of course I don't want it with the typesetter formatting.
[image]
My suspicion is that it depends on the order in which these formatting settings are applied.

I am grateful for any ideas on how to make this work.

EDIT: here is a minimal case that produces the problem, in case there's some information outside of what I provided above. I gutted it as far as I could without changing the dynamics of the problem I'm having. It's two files, the tex file (https://pastebin.com/qebkRmTN) and a cls file (https://pastebin.com/XceZ2Aad). Shoutout to the person who designed the template in the first place I guess

Comment: Can you provide the community with a complete (minimal) example where we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing? It'll speed up getting you answers and provide a frame of reference where things might have to change. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: That's a good point, I'll add it to the post. Problem is I couldn't get it to work in one file so I had to upload it to pastebin :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`friggeri-cv` is super old and creates problems with recent latex installations. You should consider getting an updated fork (there are several on github) like https://github.com/akanosora/friggeri-cv

Anyway. To change the color, you have to use the `\addfontfeature` instead of `\color`:

```
\entry
{2016 - 2018}
{Bachelor {\normalfont Pen Spinning}}
{Trump University}
{\item {\addfontfeature{Color=red}Final Grade:} A
\item {\addfontfeature{Color=black}Achievements:} Runners-up Spinner of the Year}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!